# Meaning of this two-variable asymptotic notation

Tags: asymptotics

What does $k \ln(k) = \Theta(n)$ mean? Does it mean that $k$ is a function of $n$ and we actually had better write $k(n)\ln(k(n)) = \Theta(n)$?

Comment: If $k$ and $n$ are independent, then we have constant belongs to $\Theta$, which, of course is true, but is it what you want? Otherwise, with $k(n)$ or $n(k)$, everything depends on these functions.

Comment: @zkutch It is part of an exercise of CLRS so I was wondering what it means. Exercise 3.2.8. It looks like it should be a function rather than a constant.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to find "3.2.8" - is it correct/exact numbering?

Comment: It is 3.2-8. Sorry. On page 60.

Comment: It is the last exercise before the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It roughly means "for any two constants $0 < c < C$, the following holds whenever $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $cn \leq k \ln k \leq Cn$".

For example, consider the claim "if $k = \Theta(n)$ then $(1+1/n)^k = \Theta(1)$". This means "for any two constants $0 < c < C$ there exist constants $0 < m < M$ such that following holds whenever $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $cn \leq k \leq Cn$: $m \leq (1+1/n)^k \leq M$".

The assumptions on the domain of $k,n$ are usually clear from context, but do create an ambiguity, which is why the interpretation above is only rough.

---

Problem 3.2-8 from CLRS is as follows:

> Show that $k\ln k = \Theta(n)$ implies $k = \Theta\left(\frac{n}{\ln n}\right)$.

We can expand this as follows:

> For any two constants $0<c<C$ there exist constants $0<m<M$ such that the following holds: if $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy $cn \leq k\ln k \leq Cn$ then $m\frac{n}{\ln n} \leq k \leq \frac{n}{\ln n}$.

However, this is certainly not the intended interpretation, since $\ln 1 = 0$, and so we get a division by zero! Instead, I propose the following interpretation:

> For any two constants $0<c<C$ there exist constants $0<m<M$ and $N>0$ such that the following holds: if $k,n \geq N$ satisfy $cn \leq k\ln k \leq Cn$ then $m\frac{n}{\ln n} \leq k \leq M\frac{n}{\ln n}$.

This is in the spirit of the usual definition of big O.

The idea of the proof is that since $k\ln k = \Theta(n)$, we have $\ln k = \Theta(\ln n)$. Showing this requires some arithmetic.

Comment: So I tried to introduce some $m$ and $M$ for problem 3.2-8 but I failed. Can you give me some hint on that?

Comment: I don't possess a copy of CLRS, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem says: Show that $kln(k) = \Theta(n)$ implies $k = \Theta(\frac{n}{ln(n)})$